# What to query for numeric value on "message response time" using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, response-time

I'm trying to query the average messaging response time for Facebook Pages.

The query I'm trying at the moment is this:

```
GET->   /v2.6/pageid?fields=displayed_message_response_time
```

But for some reason, I get this response:

```
{
  "displayed_message_response_time": "AUTOMATIC",
  "id": "some_id"
}
```

I don't understand why it says Automatic when I currently don't have any settings to activate a welcome message (at least none that I'm aware of). When I go to the page and check `settings->messaging`, I see that "Send Instant Replies to anyone who message your Page" is turned off.

With that said, how would I go about getting a numeric value to represent response time/rate for a page? Is my query wrong? Am I requesting the wrong field?

Comment: According to the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page displayed_message_response_time is a field you can set. So it can't be the average response time.

Comment: @WizKid So how would I go about getting a numeric representation for response time? Does such a metric exist?

Comment: No idea. At the link I gave you shows all fields that exists